Is it safe to eat hamburger if the internal temperature is 165 F but it is still pinkish in some of the area inside?
I guess I am a little confused on how to properly cook hamburger. I have ground chuck and made a 3.2 ounce patty. I also baked it in the oven and after some time the internal temperature with a food thermometer was 165 degrees F. But when I cut it in the middle some of the area inside was still slightly pink.
I am wondering if that was safe to eat. I don't eat much meat but always thought that pink means that it is undercooked. Should I let it just keep cooking until it is dark inside ignoring the thermometer? It will be lots lots higher than 165 before all the pink is gone. I am guessing easily + 200 F.

Some would say you almost ruined it (some would say you already did). Going any further, you may as well chew on a shoe. (For reference, I'm from the part of the world where https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steak_tartare and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpaccio are quite common... don't see what all the fuss is about)

Wiki  January 1992-1993 Jack In The Box.

Ground beef cooked to 165 F will not be pink.
It's quite difficult to accurately take the internal temperature of a burger or steak, because the temperature will vary widely within just a few millimeters. Finding the temperature of the middle of the burger would require extremely precise positioning at least. But to make matters worse, the temperature probe measures temperature within a certain part of its length, not just at the very tip; so there's really no way to get a precise measurement. So the temperature you measured was likely much higher than the actual minimal "internal" temperature.
As to your questions about whether you should ignore the thermometer and whether you should cook until gray and unappetizing, I will defer to national health bodies such as the USDA, and mention in passing that I do not personally follow their advice.

Thank you for your answer. Makes sense. The area that was pink was not 165 but the other areas the thermometer was in contact with were much higher. Making a thinner pattie might make it more uniform.
